# EF6 not linking foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

Using visual studio 15 for reference.

I have a foreign for centers.countrycode = countries.code (so every center will have a country associated by the above)

I however am not able to get the EF designer to update and add this key.

I have tried the following

1. I have tried to do a normal update of the model
2. Deleted the model from the EF designer and added the table
3. I have cleared all tables from the EF designer
4. I have deleted the EF ADO model and created a new one

With none of the options above am I able to get the association. This leads me to believe the issue may be related to the database engine but can see the foreign key within SSMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify the foreign key references when you updated your table in code? It's been about a year since I did any EF work, but I remember it being a pain to add Foreign Keys.

Comment: Are you sure you added fk constraint on db, either constraint FK_FOOBARCOLUMN foreign key (FOOBARTABLE) or UserId int foreign key references FOOBARTABLE(FK_FOOBARCOLUMN)?

Comment: Are you able to show any code? Are you using code first?